# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 115 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'

Tags: sql-server

```
drop table if exists #PercentPopulationVaccinated

create table #PercentPopulationVaccinated
( 
    Continent nvarchar(255), 
    location nvarchar(255), 
    date datetime, 
    population numeric, 
    new_vaccinations numeric, 
    rolling_people_vaccinated numeric
)

Insert into 
    Select  
        dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, 
        vac.new_vaccinations, 
        sum(convert(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) over (partition by dea.location order by dea.location, dea.date) as rolling_people_vaccinated
    from 
        PortfolioProject..['Covid vaccinations$'] vac
    Join 
        PortfolioProject..['Covid deaths$'] dea on dea.location = vac.location
                                                and dea.date = vac.date
    where 
        dea.continent is not null
    --order by 2,3

Select 
    *,
    (rolling_people_vaccinated / Population) * 100
from 
    #PercentPopulationVaccinated
```

I keep getting this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 115
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'

Please advise

Comment: `insert into #PercentPopulationVaccinated select ...`

Comment: Side note: you don't need a temp table for this, you can use window functions. And your `sum() over` should have `rows unbounded preceding`

Answer (score 1):

You have to write where you want [insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data:

```sql
INSERT INTO #PercentPopulationVaccinated
SELECT ...
```

Comment: Not just "should" - you **must** !

Comment: @marc_s Answer edited